# AngularJS Routing: Keep view loaded, but invisible (save scroll location and prevent reload of data)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

So I'm trying to make a single page web application that makes use of AngularJS's routing mechanism and so far it's working brilliantly, but I noticed that when the route changes, the view seems to be completely deleted and replaced with the new one.

Is there any way to keep the old view around so that it doesn't have to re-download all of its data when the user goes back to it? Also it would be nice so that their scroll position would be retained.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) I solved this problem with the [angular ui router extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky). Here you will find the *sticky states* that will perhaps do what you want. Quote from the website:

> Sticky States allows a tree of states to be long-lived, running
>   concurrently alongside one or more other state trees. This is also
>   sometimes referred to as Parallel States. The basis for this
>   functionality is to implement a "tabs" use case. Using UI-Router
>   Extras Sticky States, a single page angular app can implement
>   independent tab state trees, which operate in parallel to each other.

Does that help?

Comment: This looks very promising. Thanks! I'll check it out and be back to accept the answer if it works like it looks like it will.